# Excel ChangeLink to stop opening the destination spreadsheet

Tags: .net, excel-interop

I'm using Excel Interop in a .NET application to update broken excel links (links to other spreadsheets).  I need to run this in the background against a large number of files.

```
objWorkbook.ChangeLink(currentLinkName, newLinkName)
```

It works for most cases.  But if newLinkName is a password protected spreadsheet, Excel will pop up with a window asking for the password.  This tells me Excel is trying to open it.  I can hit cancel, and the link gets updated successfully in the source file, however, it ruins my background processing.

Is there any way to tell Excel "do not try to open the spreadsheet that I'm linking to"?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found an answer, only a work-around.  I ended up using AutoIt with a script that would Cancel any Password dialog box that popped up, over and over again.

The script:

```
Do
   WinWait("Password")
   WinActivate("Password")
   WinWaitActive("Password", "", 5)
   Send("{TAB}{ENTER}")
   Sleep(1000)
Until 1 = 2
```

Hope it helps someone.